# How to convert this to a nice Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

**How to query with Eloquent, all users without a certain type of certificate?**

Laravel 4

I've got 2 tables:

```
users table:
   ->id
   ->name


certificats table:
    ->id
    ->user_id
    ->certificate_type
```

I`m struggling  with this for hours now. Last thing i tried was:

```
$users = User::with(array('certificate' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('type','!=','SL');
}))->get();
```

This gives me all the users, but i was trying to get all the users without certificate type 'SL'.

**-- edit:**
Spencer7593's raw query below works. But i`m not getting the eloquent query to work.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT
JOIN certificates c
ON c.user_id = u.id
AND c.type = 'SL'
WHERE c.user_id IS NULL
```

The relationship:

```
public function certificate(){
    return $this->hasMany('Certificate');
}

public function certificate(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Comment: does this help:     $query->where('certificate_type','!=','SL');

Comment: No it doesn't :(  , i also tried 'certificate.type'.

Comment: The `type` refers to the column in the certificates table so that should be correct.  You aren't redefining the `$users` variable anywhere else that could be overwriting this?  And you do have the appropriate function in your `User` model for relating it to certificates?

Comment: I`m not redefining $users anywhere else. I think the relationship is set up appropiate. I added the relationship in my first post.

Comment: I believe the problem is in setting up your relationships.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL to get the result set you want is fairly simple.

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN certificates c
    ON c.user_id = u.id
   AND c.type = 'SL'
 WHERE c.user_id IS NULL
```

That's a familiar pattern called an "anti-join". Basically, it's a LEFT JOIN look for matching rows, along with rows from `users` that don't have a match, and then filter out all rows that did get a match, and we're left with rows from `users` that don't have match.

The trick is going to be getting Eloquent to generate that SQL for you. To get Eloquent to do that, you need to tell eloquent to do a LEFT JOIN, and add a WHERE clause,

maybe something like this would be close:

```
->left_join('certificate AS c', function($join){
      $join->on('c.user_id','=','user.id');
      $join->and_on('c.type','=','SL');
  })
->where_null('c.user_id')
```

**FOLLOWUP**

(For the benefit of those who might not read the comments)

Klass Terst (OP), reports syntax problems in the attempt at Eloquent (in the answer above): `left_join` needed to be replaced with `leftJoin`, and the `and_on` wasn't recognized. (The latter may have been my invention, based on the convention used in with `where`, `and_where`, `or_where`.)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
  ->select('users.id','users.name')
  ->leftJoin('certificate AS c', function($join){
     $join->on('c.user_id','=','user.id');
     $join->on('c.type','=','SL'); 
  })
  ->where_null('c.user_id');
```

Comment: Your raw query is working, but when i try your eloquent solution, i get a big object. Wich i don`t know how to use. Also i had to change left_join to leftJoin, and and_on didn`t work (does not exists?).

So i got this: 

$users = DB::table('users')
->select('users.id','users.name')
 ->leftJoin('certificate', function($join){
      $join->on('certificate.user_id','=','user.id');
      $join->on('certificate.type','!=','SL');
  })
->where_null('certificate.user_id');

dd($users);

Comment: @Klaas Terst: I would expect the raw query to work; that's a familiar pattern called an "anti-join". In this case, we aren't really interested in returning any columns from certificates; it's only returning columns from the `users` table. I definitely not an expert with Eloquent; I just took a stab at something that I thought might generate that SQL statement.

Comment: @Klaas Terst: that should really be an equality test to 'SL', not an inequality test. You  want to "mark" the rows from users that have a matching 'SL' row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your relationships.

Models

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function certificates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Certificate');
    }
}

class Certificate extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
$users = User::with(array('certificates' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('type','!=','SL');
}))->get();
return View::make('yourView')->with('users',$users);
```

View

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }} // User's name
    @foreach($user->certificates as $certificate)
        {{ $certificate->certificate_type }} // Certificate type shouldn't be 'SL'
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I hope this helps!